# marmalade ios keyboard can't output characters

Tags: ios, keyboard, marmalade

I deployed marmalade s3eKeyboard sample to iOS with Chinese language. The keyboard pops up when s3eKeyboardSetInt with S3E_KEYBOARD_GET_CHAR, but there is no Chinese character output whatever I input with Chinese input method. There is character output only in English or Number input method. The document says iphone-bundle-localisations should be set, but it make no different when set to 'zh' in deployments of MKB file. 
    Anyone had such problem or I missed something? Thank you.